# Reference Object name in array of objects

Tags: php, oop, reference

I have an array of objects and I am trying to reference the name of the object inside of the object. An example would look something like:

```
private 'inputs' => 
 array
  'displayName' => 
    object(Input)[2]
      private 'field' => string 'test' (length=17)
      private 'rules' => string 'test' (length=23)
  'inputTwo' => 
    object(Input)[3]
      private 'field' => string 'test' (length=17)
      private 'rules' => string 'test' (length=23)
```

and reference the 'disaplyName' inside object operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then add a `displayName` property to the object and set a name to it. Making something outside the object part of the required working of the object is somewhere between bad design and not possible. `$inputs['displayName']` is a variable that holds the object, you can't really create a circular dependency between the object and the variable that holds the object.

Unless I totally misunderstood what you're asking, in which case: please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: nope, explained it perfectly, thank you.  just wanted to check,